# Enum<-> string map functions

Tags: c++, templates

I currently have two maps that link enum values to strings, one direction to convert file input to internal representation, the other to print (debug) information about that internal representation. I would like to change the map to a vector for generally faster access and conversion. But then this function, which works as it should, won't work:

```
template<class T, class Y>
const T & map_value( const std::map<Y,T> &map, const Y &key )
{
    return (*map.find(key)).second;
}
```

So I tried to make it into this:

```
template<class Cont, class T, class Y>
const T & map_value( const Cont &map, const Y &key )
{
    return map[key];
}
```

But then I get no matching function call. I have just had an epiphany writing this question; `const map` has no member `operator[]`, which makes this a hard thing to do. How should I write map_value so it works as fast as possible for both `vector` and `map`?

Comment: how is `Cont` declared/defined?

Comment: The template is instantiated with `Cont` being a `const std::map<some_enum_class, std::string>` or the inverse map. I'd like to change the inverse map to a `std::vector<std::string>` and convert the `enum class` values to index values.

Comment: I suggest using `map.find()` rather than `map[]`, the former does not insert new key, value pairs.

Comment: @Thomas: but that would be slow for `vector`, where `operator[]` is faster.

Comment: @rubenvb:  You can choose to spend the time converting the text into a numeric index for the `vector` or let the `std::map` compare and dive down the binary tree.  I vote for the method that is simplest, easiest to read and understand over something more complicated that would produce negligible time savings.

Comment: @Thomas: either I don't understand what you're getting at, or you misunderstand my intention. These are pure convenience functions which I find a lot more readable than a bunch of parentheses in weird places and `.second`s in code that needs mapped values.

Comment: Have a look at [Boost.bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) -- maybe that's a more suitable data structure for your problem.

Comment: @Kerrek: yes it is, but this works for now `:)`. I'll do a small bimap of my own when I have some inspiration and time. But it would only add a layer of indirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the first definition as it is, but change the second one to cover all vectors. Use *both* in your program, the compiler will choose the appropriate version as necessary.

```
template<class T, class Y>
const T & map_value( const std::map<Y,T> &map, const Y &key )
{
    return (*map.find(key)).second;
}

template<class T>
const T & map_value( const std::vector<T> &map, size_t key )
{
    return map[key];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a *one-liner*. Surely overloading it for both types (maps and vectors) isn’t too much overhead.

In fact, this is the only way to do this. I understand the desire to have a function that’s as general as possible – good! – but you *need* to encapsulate the respective access mode (`find` vs. `operator []`). And in your case the function does nothing *but* accessing the data structure.